# Best way to embded an array of strings into a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a print dispatch queue that passes the following for each row:

```
String Name
String TemplateName
String[] dynamicTextFields
```

Other that doing a 1:m table for dynamic text fields, how would I include my Array/List of strings in a single row's cell?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a separate table with 1 to many relationship?

Comment: I could, I am simply looking for an alternative.  In Postgresql you can do this a number of ways.

Comment: Well, this is way the best option in SQL Server. I wouldn't be personally looking at anything else.

Comment: The 1:M relation is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the best way **is** a properly normalised separate table in 1 to many relationship.

Any other solution (which would invariably be storing a list in some format (XML, JSON, whatever) in a single column is inferior to that in terms of performance as well as maintainability and clarity of your design.